# Nemerle Custom Operator Problem

Tags: macros, nemerle

What would like to able to write in my code is the following.

```
c² = a² + b²
```

To begin with I tried creating a macro for `²` first.
I have tried the following.

```
  macro @² (x)
syntax (x,"²")
{
 <[ 
($x * $x)

  ]>
}
```

But I get expecting an identifier errors at the `(x)` So I tried

```
  macro @s (x)
syntax (x,"²")
{
 <[ 
($x * $x)

  ]>
}
```

Now I get Unsupported Syntax Token error at the `"²"`.

So I ask 
1. is possible to write the Operator `²` ?
2. What are the supported Syntax Tokens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, any character with an ASCII code lower than 255 and the following characters are valid for an operator: '=', '<', '>', '@', '^', '&', '-', '+', '|', '*','/', '$', '%', '!', '?', '~', '.', ':', '#', '\', '`', '(' , ')' , ';' , '[' , ']'.

We can add "²" too, but maybe a more generic approach would be better.

Comment: Found out that it only possible it may be possible, with a few changes to the lexer.